# display images in imageview on linear layout at the bottom of maps on mapclick

Tags: java, android, xml

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapInterface;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapMarker;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapPolygon;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapPolyline;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapView;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapViewTypes;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.DefaultAirMapViewBuilder;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.GoogleChinaMapType;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.MapType;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.WebAirMapViewBuilder;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnCameraChangeListener;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnCameraMoveListener;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnLatLngScreenLocationCallback;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnMapClickListener;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnMapInitializedListener;
import com.airbnb.android.airmapview.listeners.OnMapMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnCameraChangeListener, OnMapInitializedListener,
        OnMapClickListener, OnCameraMoveListener, OnMapMarkerClickListener,
        OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnLatLngScreenLocationCallback {
    Context context;
    ImageView imageView;
    int[] image = {
            R.drawable.chopper,
            R.drawable.cruise,
            R.drawable.sport,
            R.drawable.zx,
    };
    private AirMapView map;
    private DefaultAirMapViewBuilder mapViewBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapViewBuilder = new DefaultAirMapViewBuilder(this);
        map = (AirMapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        Button btnMapTypeNormal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMapTypeNormal);
        Button btnMapTypeSattelite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMapTypeSattelite);
        Button btnMapTypeTerrain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMapTypeTerrain);


        btnMapTypeNormal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
                map.setMapType(MapType.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
        });

        btnMapTypeSattelite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
                map.setMapType(MapType.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            }
        });

        btnMapTypeTerrain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
                map.setMapType(MapType.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            }
        });

        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        map.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMapInitializedListener(this);
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        map.initialize(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        AirMapInterface airMapInterface = null;

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_native_map:
                try {
                    airMapInterface = mapViewBuilder.builder(AirMapViewTypes.NATIVE).build();
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, native Google Maps are not supported by this device. " +
                                    "Please make sure you have Google Play Services installed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_mapbox_map:

                airMapInterface = mapViewBuilder.builder(AirMapViewTypes.WEB).build();
                break;
            case R.id.action_google_web_map:
                // force Google Web maps since otherwise AirMapViewTypes.WEB returns MapBox by default.
                airMapInterface = new WebAirMapViewBuilder().build();
                break;
            case R.id.action_google_china_web_map:
                airMapInterface = new WebAirMapViewBuilder().withOptions(new GoogleChinaMapType()).build();
                break;
            case R.id.action_clear_logs:
                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.airbnb.airmapview.sample/" + R.drawable.chopper);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgUri);
                imageView.setImageURI(null);
                imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (airMapInterface != null) {
            map.initialize(getSupportFragmentManager(), airMapInterface);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChanged(LatLng latLng, int zoom) {
        // appendLog("Map onCameraChanged triggered with lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: "
        // + latLng.longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapInitialized() {
        appendLog("Map onMapInitialized triggered");
        final LatLng airbnbLatLng = new LatLng(37.771883, -122.405224);
        addMarker("Airbnb HQ", airbnbLatLng, 1);
        addMarker("Performance Bikes", new LatLng(37.773975, -122.40205), 2);
        addMarker("REI", new LatLng(37.772127, -122.404411), 3);
        addMarker("Mapbox", new LatLng(37.77572, -122.41354), 4);
        map.animateCenterZoom(airbnbLatLng, 10);

        // Add Polylines
        LatLng[] latLngs = {
                new LatLng(37.77977, -122.38937),
                new LatLng(37.77811, -122.39160),
                new LatLng(37.77787, -122.38864)};

        map.addPolyline(new AirMapPolyline(Arrays.asList(latLngs), 5));
```

// Add Polygons
        LatLng[] polygonLatLngs = {
                new LatLng(37.784, -122.405),
                new LatLng(37.784, -122.406),
                new LatLng(37.785, -122.406),
                new LatLng(37.785, -122.405)
        };
        map.addPolygon(new AirMapPolygon.Builder().add(polygonLatLngs).strokeWidth(3.f).build());

```
    // Add Circle
    map.drawCircle(new LatLng(37.78443, -122.40805), 1000);

    // enable my location
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private void addMarker(String title, LatLng latLng, int id) {
    map.addMarker(new AirMapMarker.Builder()
            .id(id)
            .position(latLng)
            .title(title)
            .iconId(R.mipmap.icon_location_pin)
            .build());
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    if (latLng != null) {
        appendLog(
                "Map onMapClick triggered with lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: "
                        + latLng.longitude);

        map.getMapInterface().getScreenLocation(latLng, this);
    } else {
        appendLog("Map onMapClick triggered with null latLng");
    }
}
```

@Override
    public void onCameraMove() {
        appendLog("Map onCameraMove triggered");
    }

```
private void appendLog(String msg) {
    //imageView.setImageURI(imageView.getDrawable() + "\n" + msg);

}

@Override
public void onMapMarkerClick(long id) {
    //appendLog("Map onMapMarkerClick triggered with id " + id);
}

@Override
public void onMapMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    //appendLog("Map onMapMarkerClick triggered with marker " + marker.getId());
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(long id) {
    //appendLog("Map onInfoWindowClick triggered with id " + id);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    //appendLog("Map onInfoWindowClick triggered with marker " + marker.getId());
}

@Override
public void onLatLngScreenLocationReady(Point point) {
    //appendLog("LatLng location on screen (x,y): (" + point.x + "," + point.y + ")");
}
```

}

```
my xml code:
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.airbnb.android.airmapview.AirMapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMapTypeNormal"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMapTypeSattelite"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sattelite" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMapTypeTerrain"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Terrain" />






        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/logsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            />




    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your actual code

Comment: whats your problem? specify issue.

Comment: You can refer the code for the above given link .you can even run it.all i want is instead of scrollview at the bottom i want to display an image in imageview on map click

Comment: i have just posted the code above.i want an image tob displayed on imageview on mapclick instead of scrollable layout that show  the info

Comment: You can use ``RelativeLayout`` and set your image in bottom ``android:layout_alignBottom="true"``

Comment: Well, I have set the Framelayout Layout at the bottom and it is visible too.But when i m putting an imageview inside the Frame layout ,my imageview is not getting visible,please help me with my problem

Comment: i have set the imageView .i want help to display the image from drawable on mapclick.for people who are giving different suggestions.thanks in advance..